# javascript button returning 1

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building an ajax function that will help me update fields based on a selection in a drop down menu. However the value that keeps getting in my variable is "1" even tho it should be the username of the name selected from the drop down menu:

This is the drop down menu:

```
<select name="selectedPatient" onchange='Choice();' class="form-control">
    <option value"" disable selected>&nbsp;</option>
    \<?php 
    while($r = $results->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<option id='selectpatient' value=".$r["username"].">". $r["achternaam"] . " " . $r["voornaam"] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input id="testbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" value="Grab">
```

And this is the JS file I'm working on, the alerts keeps returning 1 for some reason.

```
$('input#testbutton').on('click', function() {
 var username = $('option#selectpatient').val();
 alert(username);
});
```

Comment: You can only have one ID `selectpatient` (ID needs to be unique), it looks as if you have multiple. Also, what is in `$r["username"]`?

Comment: the $r["username"] is a value from a MySQL database... but Karl-André Gagnon's solution worked. Thank you tho for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing `$('option#selectpatient').val();`, you select every `option` since they all have the same ID (by the way, id should be unique).

`.val()` will alway return the value of the first element in the stack.

What you actually want is the selected option, use this instead :

```
$('[name="selectedPatient"]').val();
```

Comment: @ThomasW side note, your first option is missing an `=` after the value and the attribute name is `disabled`, not `disable`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that `$r["username"]` contains a string for the username and not an integer value like 1?

You should inspect the element in your browser to double check the values of the options.

Also, you should not be giving the options in your while loop the same id. id's are supposed to be unique on a page. jQuery will automatically get the value from the selected option in your drop down menu, so if you give your  an id and the id you give is "selectedPatient", you should only have to use:

```
var username = $('#selectedPatient').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CH4x5/2/)

You have to remove all the option id. An `id` value should unique in the whole document.

After that, get the selected `option` value using :

```
$('select[name=selectedPatient]').val()
```

Comment: `> option:selected` IS NOT MANDATORY